# Truncating MongoDB oplog before EBS snapshot

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, backup

I currently have a MongoDB (on AWS) backup strategy involving automating daily snapshots of the data/journal volume on one node. The process is:

1. fsyncLock()
2. trigger AWS snapshot on volume (and wait for success)
3. fsyncUnlock()

When replacing a RS member, I launch a new instance from the snapshot and add it to the replica set. The sole issue I have is on mongo process launch there is a very long delay (~20-30 minutes for ~500GB of data) before the new node jumps into SECONDARY and replays from another member's oplog. All I see is something like this in the mongodb.log file:

```
[initandlisten] Starting WiredTigerRecordStoreThread local.oplog.rs
[initandlisten] The size storer reports that the oplog contains 659681 records totaling to 4196461664 bytes
[initandlisten] Sampling from the oplog between Dec 20 05:29:14:2 and Jan 18 06:00:00:8 to determine where to place markers for truncation
[initandlisten] Taking 335 samples and assuming that each section of oplog contains approximately 19672 records totaling to 125140475 bytes
```

1. What is Mongo doing here exactly
2. Is the oplog useful to MongoDB on launch (from snapshot) other than determining when its last optime was (I have journaling enabled)?
3. Can I remedy this by just truncating everything from the oplog except the most recent entry before taking a snapshot?

Comment: Are you aware of the [lazy loading algorithm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-restoring-volume.html) in play when you create a new volume from a snapshot?  The reason you can create such large volumes from snapshots is black magic... the data is immedately accessible "from" the volume but not immediately present "on" the volume... a "first read penalty."  I would suggest [warming up volumes created from snapshots](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html) before use to see if that resolves the issue. It should improve later performance also.

Comment: I'm aware of the lazy loading algorithm when using EBS snapshots, but I see unacceptably long startup times due to oplog sampling even after restarting mongo on an instance that has been running for some time.

Comment: Still, I would suggest that you warm up the volume to eliminate that as a possibility, because it's not documented just how lazy the lazy loading is... but my assumption based on observations is that it could be a matter of days.

Comment: The oplog is a capped collection with a fixed size, so I'm not sure truncating it would change the amount of data that needs to be read from the disk when it starts up.

Comment: I'll suggest to have a hidden and non-voting member in your replica and make sure you have sufficient voting member to elect primary. Hidden member's sole purpose will be to have backup. You can take it off for backup whenever you want and this will not trigger election. Once you are done with snapshot, put it back and it will quickly catch-up delta. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/